# How to start Nginx (or listen a http port) after PHP-FPM startup in a single container?

Tags: nginx, docker, google-cloud-platform, php-fpm

I have issues running Nginx+PHP-FPM in a single container on Cloud Run. My container is based on Alpine and manages Nginx and PHP-FPM startup by Supervisor. Overall it works fine, but there's a short timeframe between when Nginx starts listening to an HTTP port and when PHP-FPM spinups. This leads to the appearance of 502 HTTP errors with the following log message:

```
6#6: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 169.254.8.129, server: _, request: "POST / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
```

The issue here is that Cloud Run decides that the container is ready to handle requests when it opens the 8080 port. Immediately after the port opening, Cloud Run sends a request which always fails on the first attempt because FPM is not ready yet. The log message `NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 4` appears after the first request has arrived and failed.

How to manage Nginx to open its port only when PHP-FPM is ready?

Supervisor config:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
logfile=/dev/null
logfile_maxbytes=0
pidfile=/run/supervisord.pid

[program:php-fpm]
command=php-fpm -F
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
autorestart=false
startretries=0

[program:nginx]
command=nginx -g 'daemon off;'
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
autorestart=false
startretries=0
```

Nginx config:

```
# Write temporary files to /tmp so they can be created as a non-privileged user
client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_temp;
proxy_temp_path /tmp/proxy_temp_path;
fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/fastcgi_temp;
uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/uwsgi_temp;
scgi_temp_path /tmp/scgi_temp;

access_log /dev/stdout;
error_log /dev/stderr notice;

server {
        listen 8080 default_server;

        index index.php;

        keepalive_requests    10;
        keepalive_timeout     60 60;

        root /var/www/html/app/public;

        charset utf-8;

        server_name _;

        # Deny hidden files (.htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store).
        location ~ /\. {
            deny            all;
            access_log      off;
            log_not_found   off;
        }
        ########################
        # mappings             #
        ########################

        location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|ico) {
            expires 5d;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            return 404;
        }

        # Allow fpm ping and status from localhost
        location ~ ^/(fpm-status|fpm-ping)$ {
            access_log off;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

        location / {
            client_max_body_size 100m;
            try_files $uri @fpm;
        }

        location @fpm {
            # worker may take long time to finish (max 1 hour)
            fastcgi_read_timeout 3600s;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/app/public/index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME index.php;
        }
}
```

I have enabled FPM ping/status pages. Can I use them to trigger the Nginx port opening?

**Update 1:**

I tried to adjust supervisord priorities and start seconds:

```
...
[program:php-fpm]
...
priority=100
startsecs=3

[program:nginx]
...
priority=200
```

But without success:

```
[18-Dec-2020 00:31:04] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[18-Dec-2020 00:31:04] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 3
2020-12-18 00:30:30,689 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 3 seconds (startsecs)
2020-12-18 00:30:28,388 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
Error POST 502 549 B 3.286 s Google-Cloud-Scheduler https://***.run.app/
169.254.8.129 - - [18/Dec/2020:00:30:27 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 502 150 "-" "Google-Cloud-Scheduler"
169.254.8.129 - - [18/Dec/2020:00:30:27 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 502 150 "-" "Google-Cloud-Scheduler" "35.187.131.214"
2020/12/18 00:30:27 [error] 6#6: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 169.254.8.129, server: _, request: "POST / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "***.run.app"
2020-12-18 00:30:26,937 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 4
2020-12-18 00:30:26,829 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 3
2020-12-18 00:30:25,730 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2020-12-18 00:30:25,704 CRIT Supervisor is running as root. Privileges were not dropped because no user
```

Both apps still started by Supervisord simultaneously and nginx initializes first. The `RUNNING` state that Supervisord applies to apps means nothing for Cloud Run.

Answer (score 2):

For now, I ended up with the following entrypoint script that ensures that PHP-FPM is running before starting nginx:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -e

# Start PHP-FPM as a daemon in the background
php-fpm -D

# Wait until PHP-FPM is up and accepts connections. Fail if not started in 10 secs.
for run in $(seq 20)
do
  if [ "$run" -gt "1" ]; then
    echo "Retrying..."
  fi
  RESPONSE=$(
    SCRIPT_NAME=/fpm-ping \
    SCRIPT_FILENAME=/fpm-ping \
    REQUEST_METHOD=GET \
    cgi-fcgi -bind -connect 127.0.0.1:9000 || true)
  case $RESPONSE in
    *"pong"*)
      echo "FPM is running and ready. Starting nginx."
      # Run nginx without exiting to keep the container running
      nginx -g 'daemon off;'
      exit 0
      ;;
  esac
  sleep .5
done
echo "FPM has failed to start on-time, exiting"
exit 1
```

The `apk add fcgi` command is required (as for Alpine linux).

I also have a supposition that the `php-fpm -D` command always exits after FPM is ready so no loops required, just run commands one after another. But I've not tested it.

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful. I created additional script, like nginx_delay.sh. That containt your code but without php-fpm -D part. In my case supevosord still handling php-fpm. And nginx by nginx_delay.sh     command=nginx_delay.sh

Answer (score 0):

Supervisor could really use a `startdelay` option, but it doesn't currently have one. To delay the starting of nginx, instead change the command specified to Supervisor ([related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58954517/1466983)):

1. Run a shell to sleep and then start nginx directly:

   ```
   [program:nginx]
   command=bash -c "sleep 5 && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
   ...
   ```
2. Run a script which sleeps before starting nginx:

   ```
   [program:nginx]
   command=delayed-nginx.sh
   ...
   ```

   `delayed-nginx.sh`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   sleep 5
   exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'
   ```

### Original answer

I've not specifically used Supervisor, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244954/how-to-define-start-order-in-group-of-processes-using-supervisord) might work for you. This will cause Supervisor to start nginx only once `php-fpm` is running.

```
[program:php-fpm]
command=php-fpm -F
...
priority=100

[program:nginx]
command=nginx -g 'daemon off;'
...
priority=200
```

You may also need to set `startsecs` to a higher value (than the default 1 second) so that Supervisor only considers `php-fpm` to be started after it has been running for a longer time, e.g., 5 seconds:

```
[program:php-fpm]
command=php-fpm -F
...
priority=100
startsecs=5
```

[See more in the Supervisor documentation.](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-values)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But unfortunately, it doesn't work. I will add info to my question text.

Comment: Thanks for trying it anyway. How about the new answer?

Comment: Thank you for your effort in helping me to solve this issue. But I have chosen a way without supervisord (see my answer). I found a way to call the PHP-FPM server directly before running nginx.